# How to auto-accept Calendar invites from gmail on a Separate Calendar

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

In the google Calendar, I have a separate calendar where I put my travels and which I'm sharing. Now every time I buy a ticket, the reservation system sends me a confirmation as well as invitation to add the time range to my calendar.

Is there a way to auto-accept this invitation and add it to my specific Calendar (not the main one)?

Comment: Good question. How this would work out if you get an invitation from a "non-reservation system", which you don't want to accept.

Comment: I assume same way I create an email rule. Specific sender, subject and maybe parsing the actual invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been researching this pretty extensively and the answer appears to be "***No (in most cases).***"

Your "separate" calendar actually has its own EMAIL address. You can find this in the settings under integrate and it will likely have an address of: `???????@group.calendar.google.com` ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI9rO.png)).

**The bad news:** As far as I can tell, Google will NOT let secondary calendars auto-accept invites from an EXTERNAL address (i.e. a hotel, airline, your work address). This is bizarre and most maddening as ***it doesn't articulate this in the calendar settings page***.

This issue is discussed in more detail on [this thread](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/7282663?hl=en). The calendar DOES auto-accept if it comes from a gmail account, however I haven't found an easy mail filter way to get this to work around the issue. An API will do it, but that's a pain.

Hopefully a solution is proposed. To me, the "least bad" workaround would be to create a separate google account, which is not ideal.

Feel free to send feedback to google via [this link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973?hl=en).

[image: Finding calendar ID]

Comment: I wonder if you can set a Gmail rule to send it to yourself thereby the invite "comes from you".